# Integrate $\int\frac{1}{\sin^4x\cos^4x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Q:  Integrate $$\int\frac{1}{\sin^4x\cos^4x}dx$$

Attempted:

1. Let $\sin^4x=1-\cos^4x$
2. Let $\cos^4x=1-\sin^4x$
3. Change $\sin^4x$ to $\frac{1}{\csc^4x}$

They didn't work.

Comment: $sin^2{x}=1-cos^2{x}$ does not imply that $sin^4{x}=1-cos^4{x}$, since $sin^4{x}=sin^2{x}\times sin^2{x}=(1-cos^2{x})(1-cos^2{x})$; same goes to cosine.

Answer (score 5):

The change of variables $u=\cot 2x$, $du=-\dfrac{2\,dx}{\sin^22x}$ transforms the integral into
\begin{align}
16\int\frac{dx}{\sin^42x}=-8\int (1+u^2)\,du=-8\left(u+\frac{u^3}{3}\right).
\end{align}